# ajax pagination is not working in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hello i am creating task in which pagination is load from page loading as well as ajax my coding is work when page is load but after page loading ajax pagination is work for only from second link first link is not working? I am very confused so that i am share all code. need help why first link is not active?

Product.blade.php

```
@foreach($product as $product_data)
            <div class="ps-product__column">
              <div class="ps-shoe mb-30">
                <div class="ps-shoe__thumbnail">
                  <?php if(Session::has('user_id')) 
                  {
                    $user_id=Session::get('user_id');
                    $count=DB::table('wishlists')->where(['user_id'=>$user_id,'product_id'=>$product_data->product_id])->count();
                    ?>
                  <a class="ps-shoe__favorite add_to_wishlist" href="#" data-val="{{$product_data->product_id}}" <?php if($count!=0){?>style="background-color:#e68700;"<?php } ?>>
                       <i class="ps-icon-heart"></i>
                  </a>
                <?php } else {
                  ?>
                   <a class="ps-shoe__favorite" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" href="#">
                       <i class="ps-icon-heart"></i>
                    </a>
                <?php } ?>
                 <img src="{{env('IMAGE_URL')}}/images/product_single_image/{{$product_data->product_single_image}}" alt=""><a  class="ps-shoe__overlay" href="{{ route('productDetail',strtolower($product_data->product_slug))}}"></a>
                 <!--  <input type="text" name="product_id" id="product_id" val="{{$product_data->product_id}}"> -->
                </div>
                <div class="ps-shoe__content">
                  <div class="ps-shoe__variants">
                        <div class="ps-shoe__variant normal">
                            <?php
                               $images=[]; 
                               $images = explode(",",$product_data->product_multiple_image);
                             ?>
                             @foreach($images as $image)
                              <img src="{{env('IMAGE_URL')}}/images/product_multiple_image/{{$image}}" alt="">
                             @endforeach
                          </div>
                    <select class="ps-rating ps-shoe__rating">
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="1">2</option>
                      <option value="1">3</option>
                      <option value="1">4</option>
                      <option value="2">5</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ps-shoe__detail"><a class="ps-shoe__name" href="#">{{$product_data->product_name}}</a>
                    <p class="ps-shoe__categories"><a href="#">{{ $product_data->category_name}}</a>,<a href="#">{{ $product_data->subcategory_name}}</a>,<a href="#">{{ $product_data->product_name}}</a></p><span class="ps-shoe__price">{{$product_data->product_price}} Rs.</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
@endforeach
```

Productlist.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<!-- Modal -->
 <main class="ps-main">
      <div class="ps-products-wrap inverse pt-80 pb-80">
        <div class="ps-products" data-mh="product-listing">
          <div class="ps-product-action">
            <div class="ps-product__filter">
              <select class="ps-select selectpicker" name="sort_select" id="sort_select">
                <option value="">Select Option</option>
                <option value="2">Name</option>
                <option value="3">Price (Low to High)</option>
                <option value="4">Price (High to Low)</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="ps-pagination">
              {{ $product->links() }}
             <!--  <ul class="pagination">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
              </ul> -->
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="ps-product__columns" id="ps-product__columns">
            @foreach($product as $product_data)
            <div class="ps-product__column">
              <div class="ps-shoe mb-30">
                <div class="ps-shoe__thumbnail">
                  <?php if (Session::has('user_id')) 
                  {
                    $user_id=Session::get('user_id');
                    $count=DB::table('wishlists')->where(['user_id'=>$user_id,'product_id'=>$product_data->product_id])->count();
                    ?>
                  <a class="ps-shoe__favorite add_to_wishlist" href="#" data-val="{{$product_data->product_id}}" <?php if($count!=0){?>style="background-color:#e68700;"<?php } ?>>
                       <i class="ps-icon-heart"></i>
                  </a>
                <?php } else {
                  ?>
                   <a class="ps-shoe__favorite" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal" href="#">
                       <i class="ps-icon-heart"></i>
                    </a>
                <?php } ?>
                 <img src="{{env('IMAGE_URL')}}/images/product_single_image/{{$product_data->product_single_image}}" alt=""><a  class="ps-shoe__overlay" href="{{ route('productDetail',strtolower($product_data->product_slug))}}"></a>
                 <!--  <input type="text" name="product_id" id="product_id" val="{{$product_data->product_id}}"> -->
                </div>
                <div class="ps-shoe__content">
                  <div class="ps-shoe__variants">
                        <div class="ps-shoe__variant normal">
                            <?php
                               $images=[]; 
                               $images = explode(",",$product_data->product_multiple_image);
                             ?>
                             @foreach($images as $image)
                              <img src="{{env('IMAGE_URL')}}/images/product_multiple_image/{{$image}}" alt="">
                             @endforeach
                          </div>
                    <select class="ps-rating ps-shoe__rating">
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="1">2</option>
                      <option value="1">3</option>
                      <option value="1">4</option>
                      <option value="2">5</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ps-shoe__detail"><a class="ps-shoe__name" href="#">{{$product_data->product_name}}</a>
                    <p class="ps-shoe__categories"><a href="#">{{ $product_data->category_name}}</a>,<a href="#">{{ $product_data->subcategory_name}}</a>,<a href="#">{{ $product_data->product_name}}</a></p><span class="ps-shoe__price">{{$product_data->product_price}} Rs.</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
          </div>
          <div class="ps-product-action">
            <div class="ps-product__filter">
             <select class="ps-select selectpicker selectdata2" name="sort_select" id="sort_select">
                <option value="">Select Option</option>
                <option value="2">Name</option>
                <option value="3">Price (Low to High)</option>
                <option value="4">Price (High to Low)</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="ps-pagination">
              {{ $product->links() }}
            <!--   <ul class="pagination">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
              </ul> -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ps-sidebar" data-mh="product-listing">
          <aside class="ps-widget--sidebar ps-widget--category">
      <!--       <div class="ps-widget__header">
              <h3>Category</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="ps-widget__content">

              <ul class="ps-list--checked">
                @foreach($categoryList as $category )
                <li><a class="category_li" data-val="{{$category->category_id}}">{{$category->category_name}}</a></li>
                @endforeach
              </ul>
            </div>
          </aside>
          <aside class="ps-widget--sidebar ps-widget--category">
            <div class="ps-widget__header">
              <h3>SubCategory</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="ps-widget__content">
              <ul class="ps-list--checked">
                <li><a href="#">Saree</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sampoo</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </aside> -->
          <aside class="ps-widget--sidebar ps-widget--category">
            <div class="ps-widget__header">
              <h3>Category</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="ps-widget__content">
              <ul class="ps-list--checked">
                <li class="current"><a href="#">Narrow</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Regular</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Wide</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Extra Wide</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </aside>
          <div class="ps-sticky desktop">
            <aside class="ps-widget--sidebar">
              <div class="ps-widget__header">
                <h3>Color</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="ps-widget__content">
                <?php $counter=0; ?>
                @foreach($color as $colors)

                 <input type="checkbox" 
                 {{($counter == 0 ? 'checked' : '')}}
                 attr-name="{{$colors->color_name}}" class="category_checkbox"
                  id="{{$colors->color_id}}">
                  <label class="custom-control-label"
                  for="{{$colors->color_id}}"><a href="#" class="color_font">{{$colors->color_name}}</label></a><br>
                  <label>
                <!--  <input type="checkbox" id="color_id" name="colors[]" value="{{$colors->color_id}}"><a href="#" class="color_font">{{$colors->color_name}}</a>
                  </label><br> -->
               <?php $counter++; ?>
               @endforeach

              </div>
            </aside>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
@endsection
```

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $req,$id='')
    {
        $product = DB::table('sub_categories')
        ->join('categories','sub_categories.category_id','=','categories.category_id')
        ->join('products','sub_categories.subcategory_id','=','products.subcategory_id')
        ->join('colors','colors.color_id','=','products.product_color')
        ->select('products.*','categories.category_name','sub_categories.subcategory_name','colors.*')
        ->where(strtolower('sub_categories.subcategory_slug'),$id) 
        ->paginate(2);
        
        if($req->ajax()) {

          return Response::json(View::make('product', ['product' =>$product])->render());
        }
         return view('productlist',['product' =>$product]);
    }
```

Js:

```
  $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
          if (window.location.hash) {
              var page = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
              if (page == Number.NaN || page <= 0) {
                  return false;
              }else{
                 getData(page);
              }

          }

  });

   $(document).on('click', '.pagination a',function(event)
      {
         alert('hi');
          event.preventDefault();
          $('li').removeClass('active');
          $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
          var myurl = $(this).attr('href');
          var page=$(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
          getData(page);

      });

  function getData(page){
          $.ajax(
          {
              url: '?page=' + page,
              type: "get",
              datatype: "html"

          })
          .done(function(data)
          {
              $("#ps-product__columns").empty().html(data);
              //location.hash = page;

          })
          .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
          {
                alert('No response from server');

          });

  }
```

route:

```
Route::get('/getProductList/{id}','ProductListController@index')->name('getProductList');
```

Comment: specify the complete url in here `url: '?page=' + page,` use blade syntaxing `{{ url() }}`

Comment: have you checked your `getData()` is working correct or not ?

Comment: yes we get data but ajax is working for second link plz need help

Comment: @KamleshPaul any solution why first link is not working ?? only link from second is work